# Unable to draw bitmaps on top of other bitmap using Direct2D

Tags: c#, sharpdx, direct2d

I want to write a Direct2D application that draws many objects on a background image using SharpDX. But after drawing a certain number of objects, Direct2D ignores all further objects. However only if the at least 1 object is overlapping with the background image.

This is a simplified version of my rending function:

```
private void Draw()
{
    var zoom = 0.6f;
    var destRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, _windowWidth, _windowHeight);
    RenderTarget2D.DrawBitmap(_backgroundBitmap, destRect, 1.0f, BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);

    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var d = (j % 10);
            destRect = new RectangleF(i * 22 * zoom, j* 40 * zoom, 22 * zoom, 40 * zoom);
            var srcRect = new RectangleF(d * 22, 40, 22, 40);
            RenderTarget2D.DrawBitmap(_digits, destRect, 1.0f, BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear, srcRect);
        }
    }
}
```

[The result is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3shc.jpg)

Row #9 is only partly drawn and row #10 is not drawn at all.

However when there is no background image or no foreground object is touching the background image then all 1000 objects are correctly rendered.

[Result without background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf5Ih.jpg)

Even more confusing is that when I reduce the number of rows to 3 then row #3 is no longer drawing all its objects which did not happen when drawing more than 3 rows.

[Result with 3 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxsV4.jpg)

What's wrong with my application?

Below is the rest of the source code (in case it's relevant) ...

```
private void Render()
{
    RenderTarget2D.BeginDraw();
    _deviceContext.Rasterizer.SetViewport(new Viewport(0, 0, _windowWidth, _windowHeight));
    _deviceContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(_backBufferView);
    Draw();
    _swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
    RenderTarget2D.EndDraw();
}

// Initialize DX objects
public void InitDX()
{
    // SwapChain description
    var desc = new SwapChainDescription()
    {
        BufferCount = 1,
        ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(_windowWidth, _windowHeight, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
        IsWindowed = true,
        OutputHandle = DisplayHandle,
        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
        Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
    };

    // Create Device and SwapChain
    Factory2D = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory();
    SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport, new[] { SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel.Level_10_0 }, desc, out _device, out _swapChain);
    _deviceContext = _device.ImmediateContext;

    // Ignore all windows events
    SharpDX.DXGI.Factory factory = _swapChain.GetParent<SharpDX.DXGI.Factory>();
    factory.MakeWindowAssociation(DisplayHandle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

    ResizeSwapChain(_windowWidth, _windowHeight);
}

// Resizes the swap-chain
public void ResizeSwapChain(int width, int height)
{
    RenderTarget2D?.Dispose();
    _backBuffer?.Dispose();
    _backBufferView?.Dispose();
    _surface?.Dispose();

    _swapChain.ResizeBuffers(1, width, height, Format.Unknown, SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch);

    _backBuffer = Resource.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(_swapChain, 0);
    _backBufferView = new RenderTargetView(_device, _backBuffer);
    _surface = _backBuffer.QueryInterface<Surface>();
    var dpi = Factory2D.DesktopDpi;
    RenderTarget2D = new RenderTarget(Factory2D, _surface, new RenderTargetProperties(RenderTargetType.Hardware, new PixelFormat(Format.Unknown, AlphaMode.Premultiplied), dpi.Width, dpi.Height, RenderTargetUsage.None, SharpDX.Direct2D1.FeatureLevel.Level_DEFAULT));
}

// Loads a Direct2D Bitmap from a file
public static Bitmap LoadBitmapFromFile(string file)
{
    var winBitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file);

    var dxBitmap = CreateDirect2DBitmap(winBitmap, true);
    dxBitmap.Tag = file;
    winBitmap.Dispose();
    return dxBitmap;
}

// Creates a Direct2D from a System.Drawing.Bitmap
public static Bitmap CreateDirect2DBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap src, bool swapChannels)
{
    var sourceArea = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height);
    var bitmapProperties = new BitmapProperties(new PixelFormat(Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, AlphaMode.Premultiplied));
    var size = new Size2(src.Width, src.Height);

    // Transform pixels from BGRA to RGBA
    int stride = src.Width * sizeof(int);
    using (var tempStream = new DataStream(src.Height * stride, true, true))
    {
        // Lock System.Drawing.Bitmap
        var bitmapData = src.LockBits(sourceArea, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

        // Convert all pixels
        if (swapChannels)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < src.Height; y++)
            {
                int offset = bitmapData.Stride * y;
                for (int x = 0; x < src.Width; x++)
                {
                    // Not optimized 
                    byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(bitmapData.Scan0, offset++);
                    byte g = Marshal.ReadByte(bitmapData.Scan0, offset++);
                    byte r = Marshal.ReadByte(bitmapData.Scan0, offset++);
                    byte a = Marshal.ReadByte(bitmapData.Scan0, offset++);
                    int rgba = r | (g << 8) | (b << 16) | (a << 24);
                    tempStream.Write(rgba);
                }
            }
        }

        Bitmap result;
        if (swapChannels)
        {
            tempStream.Position = 0;
            result = new Bitmap(RenderTarget2D, size, tempStream, stride, bitmapProperties);
        }
        else
        {
            result = new Bitmap(RenderTarget2D, size, new DataStream(bitmapData.Scan0, stride * src.Height, true, false), stride, bitmapProperties);
        }
        src.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: First I'd try with C++ program doing the same thing, to rule out possible wrappers or runtime side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you present before you finish drawing. You should reorder those calls:

```
RenderTarget2D.EndDraw();
_swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
```